# QCreator: how to create debug build configuration

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, configuration, qt-creator

I started a new C++/Qt-Desktop project in QCreator and two build configurations were automatically created:

- a Release-Configuration where the build was created in a separate directory than the source-code
- a Debug-Configuration, where additional compiler flags were set and you could nicely debug with Valgrind

Somehow I got these build-configurations deleted (either by moving to a new computer, or opening the project on another computer - I don't know).

How to I recreate these two (apprently default) configurations for my specific project?

Comment: Are you using qmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your project.
2. Go to the *Projects* pane.
3. Select the *Build & Run* tab.
4. Select the *Build* subtab.
5. In the "Edit build configuration:" line, click *Add* dropdown, select *Build* submenu.
6. Select the *Debug* or *Release* configuration in *Build Steps*->*Details*.

Answer (score 2):

1. close your project
2. remove the .pro.user file
3. reopen the closed project